# How to get month number from Calender

Tags: java

`line` holds month name given by the user. I would like to display the month number.

example: `june -> 6`

Present code:

```
String line="june";
int monthNo = Integer.parseInt(GregorianCalendar.class.getField(line.toUpperCase()).get(line))+1;
System.out.println(monthNo);
```

What is the best method to do this?
**Edit:**
Using existing Calender classes

Comment: If you are using it frequently, I would consider creating an `enum` instead.

Comment: If you are using java 7, you can toUpperCase the input, then use a switch statement with string values.

Comment: @DwB, a switch statement with string values is rarely a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's calendar API is not the best API around. Many people therefore changed to use http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ as a quasi alternative standard. But if your application is that simple, I think hard-coding a map of names pointing to numbers would be the easiest and most efficient solution (assuming, your string is in fact a user input, otherwise, use an enum as suggested). Alternatively, you can use a [date format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use a combobox, or a control that restrain your users from typing anything, and mapping it to a constant field.

Then you can use from the GregorianCalendar

`int selectedMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;` (+1 since indexing starts at 0)
(`c` being an instance of GregorianCalendar)

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of doing this with `Calendar` I shall offer this solution.

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
    try {
        Date date = df.parse("july");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        System.out.print(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    } catch (Exception e){

    }
```

Note that this is not the best way of doing this at all and I'd suggest you use an enum instead.

Comment: +1 This is the answer using Calendar classes. It used to be as simple as `Date.getMonth() + 1` but they deprecated it.